# custom.methods.wrap didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-views

What's wrong in my code.. ? 
I'm returning an HttpResponse conditionally, yet I keep getting an error

**decorators.py**

```
def has_permission_view():
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.role == 'admin':
                if not hasattr(request.user, 'institute'):
                    messages.add_message(
                        request, messages.WARNING, "Please Add Your Institute Information")
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:add_institute'))
                elif not hasattr(request.user.institute, 'device'):
                    messages.add_message(
                        request, messages.WARNING, "Please Add Your Attendance Device Information")
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:device'))
            elif request.user.role == 'employee':
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:profile'))
        return wrap
    return decorator
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
@has_permission_view()
def index(request):
    context = {}
    d = request.user.institute.device
    zk = ZK(d.ip, d.port, timeout=5, password=0, force_udp=False, ommit_ping=False)
    try:
        conn = zk.connect()
        context['object'] = conn
    except Exception as e:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, e)
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**I Got This Error Message**
`The view custom.methods.wrap didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: What if the 1request.user.role` is not an `'admin'` and not an `employee`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  If '```request.user.role``` is not *admin* or an *employee* it should render template according to views conditions

Comment: @RiajulHashem: but there is no `else` below the `elsif` for the role check.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I got it that's the problem, but how can i return to views (ex: index view) from ```else``` statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decorated function will not return anything (hence `None`) if the `request.user.role` as an `'admin'`, but has an `.institute` with a `.device`, or the role is not `admin`, and it is not a `'employee'` either.

You need to return the result of the wrapped function in case you do not perform a redirect:

```
def has_permission_view():
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.role == 'admin':
                if not hasattr(request.user, 'institute'):
                    messages.add_message(
                        request, messages.WARNING, "Please Add Your Institute Information")
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:add_institute'))
                elif not hasattr(request.user.institute, 'device'):
                    messages.add_message(
                        request, messages.WARNING, "Please Add Your Attendance Device Information")
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:device'))
            elif request.user.role == 'employee':
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('accounts:profile'))
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrap
    return decorator
```

The combination of a `HttpResponseRedirect` and a `reverse` is a [**`redirect(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect). You can thus simplify your decorator, with:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def has_permission_view():
    def decorator(view_func):
        def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.role == 'admin':
                if not hasattr(request.user, 'institute'):
                    messages.add_message(
                        request, messages.WARNING, "Please Add Your Institute Information")
                    return redirect('accounts:add_institute')
                elif not hasattr(request.user.institute, 'device'):
                    messages.add_message(
                        request, messages.WARNING, "Please Add Your Attendance Device Information")
                    return redirect('accounts:device')
            elif request.user.role == 'employee':
                return redirect('accounts:profile')
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrap
    return decorator
```

Comment: @Wilem Van Onsem Thank you :)